# Javascript UWP - how can i insert an handler for a button which is not in the main html page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I use Visual studio 2015, updated. I created a new `UWP-js` app: i have `index.html`, `default.css` and `main.js`. I have a button called `play` with a registered  `eventListener` which change the window and visualize another HTML page, another button called `quit` which close the window. 
The code of `main.js` is:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = WinJS.Application;
    var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
    var isFirstActivation = true;

    app.onactivated = function (args) {
        if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {

        } else {
            if (args.detail.previousExecutionState == activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {

            }
        }

        if (!args.detail.prelaunchActivated) {

        }

        if (isFirstActivation) {

            document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChanged);
            args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());

            var playbutton = document.getElementById("play");
            playbutton.addEventListener("click", playhandler, false);
            var quitbutton = document.getElementById("quit");
            quitbutton.addEventListener("click", closeApp, false);
        }

        isFirstActivation = false;
    };

    function onVisibilityChanged(args) {
        if (!document.hidden) {

        }
    }

    app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {

    };

    function playhandler(eventInfo) {//apro la tavola da disegno
        window.location("drawTable.html");
    }

    function closeApp(eventInfo) {//chiudo l'app
        window.close();
    }

    app.start();

})();
```

When I click on play button, appear another HTML page (`drawTable.html`) in which there's a button called `backbutton`. Now I want that on click, I return to index.html page. Where can I register the handler of this button? I try to create another js file where I put this function:

```
function backbuttonHandler() {
    window.location("index.html");
}
```

and i wrote also in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/winjs-4.0.1/js/ui.js"></script>
    <link href="/css/drawTable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/drawTable.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <button class="myButton" id="backbutton" onclick="backbuttonHandler()">back</button>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want that on click, I return to index.html page. Where can I register the handler of this button? ...but it doesn't work!

It doesn't work because UWP doesn't support inline javascript due to security reason. So codes like `<button class="myButton" id="backbutton" onclick="backbuttonHandler()">back</button>` won't trigger the `backbuttonHandler`.

To fix the problem, you need to attach the eventhandler in JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("backbutton").onclick = function (evt)
    {
        window.location("index.html");
    }
}
```

And a suggestion: If you want to create a real UWP App, it is strongly recommended making your app a [Single Page Application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application).